# How to Loop through SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have the the code below which returns only the top result in a pivot table ie:

```
<f_fileNotesDate> <f_fileNotesTime> <f_fileNotesTime> <f_fileNotesCreatedBy>
```

What I'm trying to do is to loop through it so it returns all the lines (guessing based on @f_fileNotesDate so while there is a date return the line so it would be:

```
<f_fileNotesDate> <f_fileNotesTime> <f_fileNotesTime> <f_fileNotesCreatedBy>
<f_fileNotesDate> <f_fileNotesTime> <f_fileNotesTime> <f_fileNotesCreatedBy>
<f_fileNotesDate> <f_fileNotesTime> <f_fileNotesTime> <f_fileNotesCreatedBy>
```

But everything I've tried has failed my starting code is:

```
DECLARE @f_fileNotesDate DATE, @f_fileNotesTime TIME, @f_fileNotesDesc 
NVARCHAR(100), @f_fileNotesCreatedBy NVARCHAR(25)
SELECT 

ISNULL(f_fileNotesDate, '') as f_fileNotesDate, 
ISNULL(f_fileNotesTime, '') as f_fileNotesTime, 
ISNULL(f_fileNotesDesc, '') as f_fileNotesDesc,
ISNULL(f_fileNotesCreatedBy, '') as f_fileNotesCreatedBy

FROM (
SELECT field_value, field_name
FROM [RWADMIN].[RV_ACTIVITY_FIELDS] WHERE activity_id = ${ID_LIST}
) d 

pivot (
MAX(field_value)
FOR field_name in (f_fileNotesDate, f_fileNotesTime, f_fileNotesDesc, 
f_fileNotesCreatedBy)
) piv;
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: You might get more feedback if you add a SQL Server tag to the question.

Comment: Thanks Kirby I've added one.

Comment: Why "loop" at all? Just run a query which *"returns all the lines"* automatically. I could add an answer if you provided A: "sample data" and B: the "expected result" - but right now I cannot fathom what that query does.

Comment: Thanks @Used_By_Already unfortunately it only returns the last line of data Entered. Basically some sample data would look like:

`14/08/2017    08:30     Some file note text here      Test_User`
`13/08/2017    06:20     Some sort of file note          Test _User`
`02/08/2017    11:25      First file note entered          Test_User`

What I'm expecting is a list with four columns with each line returned.

Comment: The main reason for the loop is it will be used outside of Microsoft SQL Server using another application which will need the loop to return the different lines.